# Chrome: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, jplayer

With the last Chrome update (Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)), when I try to play (not autoplay) a video using jplayer, I obtaining this exception in Chrome console and I'm not able to play the video. I hadn't this problem (and no warning) in Chrome until friday. I haven't this problem in Firefox and Internet Explorer where I can see normally the video.

I have just tried this: [DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674223/domexception-failed-to-load-because-no-supported-source-was-found), but I am still not able to see the video

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Video Player in html and jquery, i think its a easy workarround, may it help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        
    var vidurlmp4 = "../beispieldateien/jh-seo.mp4"; // Change the Url to your video / ändere die adresse zu
      $('#video-player').html('<video  controls> <source src='+vidurlmp4+' type="video/mp4"></video>');
```

});

You can test [here](http://www.hiti-seo.com/programmierung/create-video-player-jquery/video-player-html-jquery.html#code)