# Fragmented MP4 doesn't show up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, video-streaming

But works fine in Firefox.

Google Chrome version:61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Mozilla Firefox version: 56.0.2 (64-bit)

My video is fragmented MP4 streamed over WebSocket to a client html page,where it's being fetched into MSE. The video codec  is H264 Main Profile. The video info has been check  both in FFPROBE and other inspectors to make sure the data integrity is ok. The following flags are used when muxing the FMP4:

```
 "empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe"
```

I also double checked that the first fragmented is the so called " initializing segment" with size of 24 bytes.
As I said, Firefox playback is fine.

Here is the client code (mostly borrowed from [here](https://github.com/eventials/poc-mp4-websocket/blob/master/public/index.html)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>MSE Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>MSE Demo</h1>
   <div>
      <video id="video1" controls width="80%"   autoplay="true"> </video>
   </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {

        var mime = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D401E"';

        if (!MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mime)) {
            document.querySelector('h1').append(' - Unsuported mime type :(');
            return;
        }

        var buffer;
        var websocket;
        var buffer_size = 4 * 1024 * 1024;
        var buffer_index = 0;
        var frag_mp4_buffer = new Uint8Array(buffer_size);
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        var mediaSource = new MediaSource();

        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceended', function (e) { console.log('sourceended: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclose', function (e) { console.log('sourceclose: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });
        mediaSource.addEventListener('error', function (e) { console.log('error: ' + mediaSource.readyState); });

        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        video.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', function (e) {
            console.log('sourceopen: ' + mediaSource.readyState);
             //doesn't help:
            //  var playPromise =  video.play();
            // In browsers that don’t yet support this functionality,
            // playPromise won’t be defined.
            /*
            if (playPromise !== undefined) {
                playPromise.then(function () {
                    // Automatic playback started!
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // Automatic playback failed.
                    // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback.
                });
            }
            */

            buffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mime);

            buffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (e) {
                if (video.duration && !video.currentTime) {
                    video.currentTime = video.duration;
                }
            });

            var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + document.location.hostname + ':8080');
            websocket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

            websocket.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                var data = new Uint8Array(e.data);
                console.log("got packet! size:" + data.length);
                if (data.length) {
                    if ((buffer_index + data.length) <= buffer_size) {
                        frag_mp4_buffer.set(data, buffer_index);
                        buffer_index = buffer_index + data.length;

                        if (!buffer.updating && mediaSource.readyState == 'open')
                         {
                            var appended = frag_mp4_buffer.slice(0, buffer_index);
                            buffer.appendBuffer(appended);
                            frag_mp4_buffer.fill(0);
                            buffer_index = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }, false);
        }, false);
    })();
    </script>
 </body>
```

Another important info,you can see I commented out the `video.play()` call. That's actually the only place which throws an error when the app start:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no
>   supported source was found

I tried the following solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674223/domexception-failed-to-load-because-no-supported-source-was-found) :

```
      var playPromise =  video.play();

      if (playPromise !== undefined) {
                playPromise.then(function () {
                    // Automatic playback started!
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // Automatic playback failed.
                    $(document).on('click', '#video1', function (e) {
                        var video = $(this).get(0);
                        if (video.paused === false) {
                            video.pause();
                        } else {
                            video.play();
                        }

                        return false;
                    });
                });
       }
```

But it changed nothing. The video area is white always.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into a similar issue where I could only get my fragmented mp4 to play on firefox, but not on chrome, using this [mse example](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/netfix/blob/gh-pages/demo/bufferAll.html). I was trying to deliver a complete file first instead of sending it via websocket because I wanted to make sure that my fragmented mp4 was formatted properly. The issue I found was that in my ffmpeg command, if I inlcuded `-an` to removed the audio, then my file would not play in chrome, but still worked in firefox. Using no audio flag or specifically using `-c:a libfdk_aac` allowed my mp4 to play on chrome and firefox. Also, you should only need `-movflags +dash` instead of all of those other movflags. For reference on my code snippets below, I am using an rtsp feed from an ip camera that is encoded with h264 video, hence the `-c:v copy`.

> tested on mac, worked on firefox AND safari but NOT chrome:

`ffmpeg -i input_source -an -c:v copy -f mp4 -movflags +dash dash.mp4`

> tested on mac, worked on firefox AND safari AND chrome

`ffmpeg -i input_source -c:v copy -f mp4 -movflags +dash dash.mp4`

`ffmpeg -i input_source -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v copy -f mp4 -movflags +dash dash.mp4`

> ***edit I just found out more information of why the encoding of audio was relevant to playback on chrome. I had the mimetype/codec wrong and chrome was not as forgiving as firefox and safari.**
>   `var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';`
>   I changed it to `var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"';` and my mp4 that was encoded **without audio** played in chrome, as well as the other browsers. Perhaps you have audio but did not include the audio portion of the codec? Or maybe your video codec is not the right one for your video? It is hard to say without seeing your full ffmpeg command that was used to create the file.
>
> ***2nd edit. I made a [little project](https://github.com/kevinGodell/live-stream-media-source-extensions) to test live streaming mp4 on media source extensions using ffmpeg, nodejs, express, and socket.io.
>   Its a little rough around the edges, but it mostly works.**

Comment: This and removing `-frag_size` seems to fix the issue for me. thanks!

Comment: @MattiasWadman Since my previous post, I found another little setting that helped with cross browser compatibility. Chrome was having trouble playing back my live feed when having `sourceBuffer.mode` set to  `sequence` in the media source extension player. For ffmpeg, I changed my `movflags` to `+dash+negative_cts_offsets` and chrome no longer gave warnings/errors about timestamps. I have included these settings in my latest project https://github.com/kevinGodell/ffmpeg-streamer

Comment: Ok good to know! do you know if it's possible to manipulate the audio/video pts when streaming dash fragments like this? i've tried to use `setpts` and `asetpts` ffmpeg filters but they seem to be ignored or reset to zero. If i remove all movflags and just write mp4 to a file (not streamed to stdout) the pts can be offsetted. Im working on project were i want to transcode part of file dynamically and play it in video element (to be able to seek). Also done some experiment with changing SourceBuffer.timestampOffset before appendBuffer but that feels strange.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Firefox and Chrome:

```
ffmpeg -i input.any \
  -f mp4 \
  -movflags faststart+separate_moof+empty_moov+default_base_moof \
  -acodec aac -b:a 256000 \
  -frag_duration 500K \
   output.mp4
```

which should also work with SourceBuffer from the Meadia Source Extension API. The Mime-Type you're looking here for is `audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"`.

At this point however, I am not sure how to seek inside this file (if that's even possible) e.g. if you don't want to send the entire file to a client but start from a particular timestamp and jump directly to a `[moof][mdata]`-pair to start loading from.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not like it when videos don't have audio.

If you're generating an HLS playlist using a m4s segments (which are in essence chunks of a fragmented mp4) then you'll also need to make sure that there is audio or it will simply not play.

This one should work for all browsers:

```
ffmpeg -y -i SOURCE.mp4 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -af apad -shortest -c:v copy -movflags empty_moov+default_base_moof+frag_keyframe+omit_tfhd_offset -write_tmcd off FRAGMENTED_WITH_PADDED.mp4
```