# Asp.net 2.0 Web Pages_play file mp3, mp4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I want to play `mp3 and mp4` files in Pages using `html5`, `JavaScript` and `jQuery`.
If files are in a project that play files it works but if the files are in another folder on my computer( E, D or Download...) they don't run.
**Error:**

> Error :searchms.aspx:1491 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

```
(play.click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); song.play();  // this error
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome 50, a `play()` call on `audio` (or `video`) element returns `Promise` instance (further details can be found in [this reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise?hl=en)). You should add detection for successful play and the `Promise` instance is fulfilled like this example:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="song" src="../path/to/audio/file.mp3" />
<button id="play">Play</button>
```

**JS**

```
var play = $('#play'); // example
play.click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var playback = document.querySelector('#song').play();
    if (playback !== undefined) {
        playback.then(function() {
            // do something
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // do something else
        });
    }
});
```

Another example can be found in [HTMLMediaElement.play() Returns a Promise Sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/play-return-promise/).

If it turns to be CORS issue, try to set `crossorigin` attribute as anonymous one, then ensure that response header returned from server contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`:

```
var song = document.getElementById('song');
song.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');

// or this:
song.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
```

Related issue:

[DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674223/domexception-failed-to-load-because-no-supported-source-was-found/40238567)