# How to play audio file with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-audio-api

I'm trying to play an audio file in my vue.js project as such:

```
import sound from '../../recordings/sound.mp4'
const audio = new Audio(sound) 
audio.play()
```

This works perfectly well, but `import` may only appear at the top level - not within a function that would ideally accept any audio file.

Now I tried doing it this way:

```
const audio = new Audio('../../recordings/sound.mp4') 
audio.play()
```

But then I get this error:

> DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

I found a solution to this strange error in this answer:
[DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674223/domexception-failed-to-load-because-no-supported-source-was-found)

The solution was to use the import statement - but the issue is the the import statement can only be used at the top level - not within a function.

So how can I dynamically play an audio file with vue.js?

Comment: The error means the source file cannot be played. Please make sure the file exists and can be played in the browser.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - if you will review the question again you will notice that the file most certainly does exist because I am able to play it using the first code snippet but not with the 2nd code snippet. The two paths in both snippets are identical

Comment: No they're not. One is a local import, the other will be what the browser uses. If the file is not available then it won't play

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I think I understand. How can I make the file available to the browser? It's a vue.js project and the recording is parallel to the vue component as per the path above.

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html serve the audio file as a static asset. Then use that path in `new Audio(...)`

Comment: It's not a good idea to import an audio file, better host your file as a static asset somewhere in your public directory and use that in the browser directly

Comment: @Lk77 - how to I reference the public directory? I've tried doing `var audio = new Audio("../../public/recordings/sound.mp4");` but this still results in the error `DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found`. I have ensured that the file is there.

Comment: You should do `var audio = new Audio("recordings/sound.mp4");` it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can import your audio file inside a function using [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)

```
(async () => {
  let sound = await import('../../recordings/sound.mp4');
  const audio = new Audio(sound);
  audio.play();
})();
```

Comment: Seems like it is the right answer, but vue keeps telling me 'module not found' when importing the sound file , although the path is correct .