# next.js Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources for playing video

Tags: reactjs, dom, video, next.js, use-ref

In next.js app I fetch video urls successfully and want to render them in my app but getting this error: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources"

I set a video element

```
 <video
        loop
        onClick={onVideoPress}
        ref={videoRef}
        src={url}
        style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
      />
```

this is ref:

```
   const videoRef = useRef(null);
```

this is the click handler:

```
const onVideoPress = () => {
    if (playing) {
      videoRef.current.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
    } else {
      videoRef.current.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }
  };
```

this is the source error that chrome tools show:

[image]

- I wrapped  `videoRef.current.play();` with `try/catch` but i got same error:
- I tried this:

  ```
   if (videoRef.current !== null) {
        videoRef.current
          .play()
          .then(() => {
            setPlaying(true);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            console.error("eror in play video", e);
          });
      }
  ```

and add  `crossorigin="anonymous"` on video element but still have the same issue

When I click on the video component, `videoRef.current` changes to:

[image]

Comment: That error may be because of a CORS issue from the URL you're trying to play content from. See [DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674223/domexception-failed-to-load-because-no-supported-source-was-found).

Comment: @juliomalves I wrote `if (videoRef.current !== null) {
      videoRef.current
        .play()
        .then(() => {
          setPlaying(true);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.error("eror in play video", e);
        });
    }
` and set ` crossorigin="anonymous"` but did not fix it